# Forwarding URL .htaccesss file

Tags: .htaccess

I know that I am missing a little part but I want to forward everything that comes after blog.example.com/ to a new url example.com/posts. I just want it to go to the exact url example.com/posts and not to new urls.

Here is what I have:

```
Redirectmatch 301 http://blog.example.org/ http://www.example.org/posts
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't match the hostname in the pattern of a `RedirectMatch` directive. You can use mod_rewrite's `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.org/posts [L,R=301]
```

Comment: it's still giving me a server error when I type in a url like blog.example.org/post or anything else after blog.example.org